# MVC Custom Model attribute to HTML attribute

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, attributes, adapter

I'm currently misusing (for as far as I know) a ValidateAttribute to get a model attribute displayed when generating a HTML view.

I have a model property, with a custom attribute (enabling some clientside Json handling):

```
[JsonResultPair("Zipcode","City")]
public virtual string City { get; set; }
```

Which is used  in the view like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "A", tabindex = 10, title = "B" })
```

Which results in:

```
<input class="A" data-val="true" data-val-pair="" data-val-pair-fld="City" data-val-pair-src="Zipcode" id="City" name="City" tabindex="10" title="B" type="text" value=""/>
```

***But ideally, I want to leave out the data-val-pair="" attribute, normally used for holding error messages, because this isn't an actual validation. And I'd like to use data-value (or whatever custom name after data-) instead of data-val. Any ideas on how to do this?***

My current attribute implementation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonResultPair: ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly String _source;
    private readonly String _field;

    public JsonResultPair(String source, String field)
    {
        _source = source;
        _field = field;
    }

    public String Source { get { return _source; } }
    public String Field { get { return _field; } }
}
```

My current adapter implementation:

```
// thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120792/how-can-i-have-a-custom-validationattribute-rendered-as-a-data-val-xx-attribut
public class JsonResultPairAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<JsonResultPair>
{
    private const String Pair = "pair";
    private const String PairSource = "src";
    private const String PairField = "fld";

    public JsonResultPairAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, JsonResultPair attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = Pair
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add(PairSource, Attribute.Source);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add(PairField, Attribute.Field);

        return new []{ rule};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this blog contains a very good / detailed answer for your question:
[add html attributes](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx)

The basics steps are:

1. create a custom attribute (which you've already done), don't inherit from the validation attributes
2. create a metadata provider, based on the data annotation provider, which will also read / add your attributes to the model's metadata
3. either create a template for the Textbox, or within the view itself query Model.Metadata, to get the custom attribute and its value you are using.