# Custom Validation using ValidationAttribute does not fire Client side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, componentmodel

I have created a custom validator deriving from ValidationAttribute. My undertsandng is that it will generate enough meta data for the client side script to automatically validate (using jquery.validate). The custom validator is working fine in server side. But it does not fire error message in the client side. (Other default validators like “StringLength“ are working fine in the client side too.) How do we correct it?

```
public class Person
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [CustomStartLetterMatch("FirstName")]
    [StringLength(5,ErrorMessage = "Must be under 5 characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Range(18,50,ErrorMessage="Must be between 18 and 50")]
    public int Age { get; set; }


}


public sealed class CustomStartLetterMatch : ValidationAttribute
{

    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = " First letter of '{0}' must be same as first letetr of '{1}'";
    private string _basePropertyName;

    public CustomStartLetterMatch(string basePropertyName)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        _basePropertyName = basePropertyName;
    }


    //Override FormatErrorMessage Method
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(_defaultErrorMessage, name, _basePropertyName);
    }


    //Override IsValid
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Get PropertyInfo Object
        var basePropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_basePropertyName);
        var baseValue = (string)basePropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        var currentValue = (string)value;


        string firstLetterBaseValue = baseValue.Substring(0, 1);
        string firstLetterCurrentValue = currentValue.Substring(0, 1);

        //Comparision
        if (!string.Equals(firstLetterBaseValue, firstLetterCurrentValue))
        {
            var message = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
            return new ValidationResult(message);
        }

        //Default return - This means there were no validation error
        return null;
    }

}
```

VIEW

```
@model MyValidationTEST.Person

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>

@*UnObtrusive*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>




@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
    </div>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

READING:

1. [IValidatableObject in MVC3 - client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748703/ivalidatableobject-in-mvc3-client-side-validation)
2. [In ASP.NET MVC3 how do you stay DRY with very similar but slightly different viewmodels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987128/in-asp-net-mvc3-how-do-you-stay-dry-with-very-similar-but-slightly-different-vie)
3. http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/22/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-ii-client-code.aspx
4. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html
5. [ASP.NET MVC 3 client-side validation with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784943/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-validation-with-parameters)
6. [How can I have a custom ValidationAttribute rendered as a 'data-val-xx' attribute on the client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120792/how-can-i-have-a-custom-validationattribute-rendered-as-a-data-val-xx-attribut)
7. [Clientside Validation in "Self Validate Model" in ASP.NET-MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155816/clientside-validation-in-self-validate-model-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My undertsandng is that it will generate enough meta data for the
>   client side script to automatically validate (using jquery.validate).

Your understanding is wrong. You cannot possibly expect that there's enough metadata in order to generate client validation. In this `IsValid` method you could do absolutely anything. You could even call an unmanaged C++ library to perform validation. You cannot possibly expect that ASP.NET MVC 3 will reflect this on the client.

You need to implement [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) and add a custom adapter if you want to enable client validation for such custom validation logic. In this adapter you have to reimplement the same logic you did on the server but using javascript this time.

Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784986/29407). And here's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8284207/29407).

As you can see client side validation works fine with some simple rules such as Required and stuff, bit once you start doing some real validation you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So it is not really DRY? :-) We need to repeat if it is custom validation.?

Comment: @Lijo, yes, it's not DRY. But that's how it is. Why bother implementing such custom rules on the client at all? Of course if you absolutely need it, prepare yourself to write javascript.

Comment: @Lijo, `Self Validate approach`? What do you mean?

Comment: It is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154231/how-does-dataannotations-really-work-in-mvc

Comment: @Lijo, that's for server side validation. Nothing to do with client side. It basically tells you that you could either have your model implement the `IValidatebleObject` interface to perform a server side validation or use custom validation attribute as in your code.

Comment: @Lijo Only property level validators can emit client-side validation, mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748703/ivalidatableobject-in-mvc3-client-side-validation

Comment: @wnascimento, actually to be more precise `Only property level validators that implement IClientValidatable can emit client-side validation`. Because the OP already has a property level validator and yet no client side validation at all.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349766/asp-net-mvc3-validationtype-modelclientvalidationrule ?

Comment: @Lijo, sure, but first take care of your previous questions. Is there something else you would like to this discuss about this particular topic? If not consider closing it by marking an answer.